# "Parameter is not valid" when Converting byte to image in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I got one error "Parameter is not valid" when i converting database byte array to image from this code.

```
try
{
    DataTable dt = dbo.GetRecordsWithQuery("select * from Users where UserID='" +Session["userid"].ToString()+ "'");
    byte[] image_user = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Image"]; // from this i got the error. Also the image_user dimension is 13
    System.Drawing.Image myimage = BinaryToImage(image_user);
    myimage.Save(Server.MapPath("~/User/images/profileImg/img1.jpg"));
    img1.ImageUrl = "~/User/images/profileImg/img1.jpg";
    url = img1.ImageUrl;
}
```

...

```
public static System.Drawing.Image BinaryToImage(byte[] binaryData)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(binaryData);
    System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

Comment: What is the schema of datatable [users]?

Comment: can u debug and check the value of `dt.Rows[0]["Image"]` whether coming value is valid to convert or not.